# How do I upload a complete Drupal website?

Tags: 8

I have received a complete website template that I need to upload to Drupal. However, there seems to be files already at the root access. I have the full images, index, data base. Everything that needs to be uploaded.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What do you mean by _files already at the root access_?

Comment: You can not upload drupal site just by copy file on root of domen. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install

Comment: Drupal has content types. You need to build them according your needs. And/Or adjust the markup via their templates.